# Negotiation, Negotiating Point

Tags: word-choice, modifiers

Could it be that  "***negotiating*** points" and "***negotiation*** points" are different?  Or is my question hairsplitting?

Comment: They could also be [**negotiable** points](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22negotiable+points%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Same difference. I don't much like [**negotiatable** points](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22negotiable+points%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22negotiatable+points%22) though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  How are they different?

Comment: Because [by most people's standards](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=negotiatable%2Cnegotiable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnegotiatable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegotiable%3B%2Cc0) "**negotiatable**" isn't a valid word in the first place. As implied by the relative prevalence shown in my link here, and the two in the first comment. FWIW, it's not listed in OED either - you'll only find "**negotiable**" there.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely identical. I cannot think of any possible differences.

The first means "points to use when negotiating" and the second means "points to use during negotiation". There is no semantic difference between using something "during negotiation" versus "when negotiating".

Comment: I find "talking point" in dictionaries, but not "negotiating point".

Comment: That's more a reflection on the dictionary than the language :) negotiating point is the equivalent of a talking point but in the specific context as a negotiation. A debating point would be similar.